# ChromeCast MediaRouter.Callback not allowing @Override

Tags: android, google-cast

Trying to get Chromecast support up and running using the HelloText-Android tutorial.  At the point where I set the MediaRouter.Callback it's not allowing me to override the proper methods.

```
import android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider;
import android.support.v7.media.MediaRouteSelector;
import android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter;

private MediaRouter mMediaRouter;
private MediaRouteSelector mMediaRouteSelector;
private MediaRouter.Callback mMediaRouterCallback;


private class MyMediaRouterCallback extends MediaRouter.Callback {

    @Override
    public void onRouteSelected(MediaRouter router, RouteInfo info) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRouteSelected");
        // Handle the user route selection.
        mSelectedDevice = CastDevice.getFromBundle(info.getExtras());

        launchReceiver();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRouteUnselected(MediaRouter router, RouteInfo info) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRouteUnselected: info=" + info);
        teardown();
        mSelectedDevice = null;
    }
}
```

This gives me:

```
The method onRouteUnselected(MediaRouter, RouteInfo) of type MyApp.MyMediaRouterCallback must override or implement a supertype method
```

and

```
The method onRouteUnselected(MediaRouter, RouteInfo) of type MyApp.MyMediaRouterCallback must override or implement a supertype method
```

I am using Java Compiler 1.6, and have no other override errors throughout the project.
Any thoughts?

**UPDATE 1:
Incidentally,  if I start a new Activity in the same project and copy and paste the code directly from the tutorial there is now error. It seems like it may be an issue with my imports, but I've been through them numerous times and can't find a difference.**

Thanks
Josh

Comment: I've added the `google-cast` tag to your question. There are Google devs who monitor that tag and may be able to help.